# Get precise date AngularJS

Tags: javascript, date

I want to get the date of day - 1 or month -1 for example, how can I manage that?

For now I have that:

```
resolve: {
  data: function($route, $http, $filter) {
    var today = new Date();
    var formattedDate = $filter('date')(today, 'yyyyMMdd');
    return $http.get('./app/sources/stats/'+$route.current.params.mag+'/'+$route.current.params.mag+'_20170205.json').then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: *"I want to get the date of day - 1 or month -1"* – can you decrypt this?

Comment: you can use getDate() and getMonth() function what you are asking is unclear

Comment: try this  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date
it might help you.

Comment: I prefer to work with moment.js

Comment: @VinodLouis Yep thx, I used getDate and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date(today);
yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
```

same goes for `setMonth` and `getMonth`

Comment: I also used the filter to get yyyyMMdd --> var previousDay = new Date(today);
 var formattedDate2 = $filter('date')(previousDay.setDate(today.getDate()-1), 'yyyyMMdd');


Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did to add days in my project. Maybe this will help you!

```
var app = angular.module('my-app', []);
  app.controller("my-controller", function($scope) {
   $scope.name = "world";
   $scope.mydate = new Date("2016-08-16T15:10:10.530Z");
   var numberOfDaysToAdd = 5;
    $scope.newdate = $scope.mydate.setDate($scope.mydate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 
  });
```